# Bootstrap 3 making right column shift underneath left column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im using Bootstrap 3, I have 2 columns next to each other, but i want to make the right column shift underneath the left column when the screen gets smaller.

What I have is as follows;

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    This is the left column
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    This is the right column
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is doesn't shift when the screen gets smaller is because you are using `col-xs-` classes.  That tells bootstrap to show them next to each other on the smallest screen, and anything larger.

Also, you don't need the extra row for what you're doing.

Here's how you would show them next to each other on any screen medium or larger using `col-md-` classes:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8">
            This is the left column
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            This is the right column
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

If you wanted to show them next to each other on a large screen and stacked on anything smaller, you would use `col-lg-` classes.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense ... Thank you very much, this worked